# Cloning a type?

Tags: c++, templates, types, typedef, substitution

In C++, two types can have the *same definition* without being the same type.

For instance, consider `A` and `B` here:

```
struct A {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

struct B {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

static_assert(!std::is_same<A, B>::value, "");
```

`A` and `B` are interchangeable in the sense that, if I had a program that
used only `A`, and replaced every instance of `A` with `B`, it would compile
and work in the same way. If you like, they are the same in the sense of "duck typing", but not identical.

Something similar seems to happen with certain fundamental types.

When I compile C++ programs on my 32-bit machine, I find that `int` and `long` both represent a signed 32 bit integer, and are interchangeable, while not being the same type.

---

This is different from what happens when I "duplicate" a type with `typedef`.

```
struct A {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

typedef A B;

static_assert(std::is_same<A, B>::value, "");
```

`typedef` doesn't create a new type, it creates a new name for the same type,
it seems.

---

Naively, one might imagine that a typical compiler uses some sort of compiler intrinsic
to implement fundamental types. For instance, you might imagine that there is some
sort of template `__signed_integer`, and then in some internal header file,
you find something like this

```
typedef __signed_integer<4> int;
typedef __signed_integer<4> long;
```

And it would be different on different implementations.

However since `typedef` doesn't do the right thing (`int` and `long` are supposed
to be distinct, even if they have the same size), this can't actually be how
it works -- there must be some other mechanism.

---

This question is not actually about compiler implementation details: Rather, the
question is, is there a way within user-level, standard C++ to "typedef" a type
in a way that makes a copy rather than an alias?

I.e. is there a way to get the same effect as the code:

```
struct A {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

struct B {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

static_assert(!std::is_same<A, B>::value, "");
```

but without writing the definition twice, and instead writing someting like

```
struct A {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

typedef clone<A> B;

static_assert(!std::is_same<A, B>::value, "");
```

?

(I have no particular use in mind, it's merely a curiosity.)

Comment: With `typedef` you don't duplicate any type even with quotes surrounding the duplication, you just create an alias, i.e. another name for the same entity.

Comment: Typedef doesn't do the right thing? What the heck does that mean? What is your expected "right thing"?

Comment: Why would you want to clone the definition of a class? At most you want to clone objects.

Comment: @nbro I already needed such a "type cloning", e.g. for defining distinct, but similar states in `boost::msm`

Comment: @m.s. Well that's why OOP exists, no?

Comment: Related to [how-do-i-strongly-typedef-non-primitive-types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207202/how-do-i-strongly-typedef-non-primitive-types)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply inherit:

```
struct A {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

struct B : A{};

static_assert(!std::is_same<A, B>::value, "");
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c732010b536c1e8)</kbd>

You can still use your `clone` if you want:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

template <typename T>
struct clone : public T
{
   using T::T;
   template<typename ...Ts>
   clone(Ts&&...ts):T{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... } {};
};

using B = clone<A>;

static_assert(!std::is_same<A, B>::value, ""); 

int main()
{
    A a{1,2};
    B b{1,2};
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ad1819d544eabb0)</kbd>

Comment: But `void f(const A&); B b; f(b);` would works, as `B` is a `A`

Comment: @Jarod42 not sure what you mean, is this a reply to Yakk's now deleted comment?

Comment: No, it is a comment for you. I said that A and B are related types.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see. It then really depends which level of type relationship/distinctness is required for the OP

Answer (score 3):

You can use templates for this:

```
template <int>
struct foobar {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

using A = foobar<1>;
using B = foobar<2>;
```

That way `A` and `B` are different types, but it allows you to make as many as you want without repeating the definition.

Comment: The drawback is, without a shared base type these are all unrelated and not convertible, unless you provide the conversion operations explicitly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The "drawback" seems to be the expected behaviour for OP, as I understan : they are distinct type.