# BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF and move semantics

Tags: c++, boost, move-semantics, strong-typing

From what I can [see](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp) BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF  does not support move semantics(no move ctor/assignment).

Is this just an oversight(nobody updated old macro) or is there a more fundamental reason why strong typedefs are limited in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental reason would be that many boost libraries are still targetting pre-c++11 standard compilers¹, i.e. compilers that do not support move semantics.

I suppose for some compilers the tricks in Boost Move might be used, but I'm not sure that would be easy to apply transparently to strong typedefs.

However, I'd always roll my own strong typedef to do the job, as I've suggested fro other reasons, e.g. [How do I strongly typedef non-primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207202/how-do-i-strongly-typedef-non-primitive-types/23212458#23212458)

---

¹ Boost Serialization is definitely one of these libraries

Comment: Can they not just check the c++ version macro to see if move semantics is supported? Or it is impossible to do macro checking when you are already in a macro? 

Sorry for stupid question, but I do not know anything about macros beside simple things.

Comment: Yes, "they" can also do this, but why depend on/wait for some library dev? Of course, you can consider **also** [filing a feature request/improvement](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/issues) suggestion.

Comment: However, I **think** strong_typedef.hpp is/was basically an implementation detail for Boost Serialization only. Here you see Robert Ramey sate _["for a number of reasons I don't use BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF in the serialization library anymore. I eventually concluded that it's usage was a mistake - at least in my context."](https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/issues/201)_ (17h ago). I'd suggest looking at some other library, like [@foonathan's `type_safe` library, here](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe/blob/master/example/strong_typedef.cpp)